# async/await not working in NodeJS, it doesn't wait

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I'm calling 2 REST API endpoints using Axios in NodeJS.I'm trying to make that the code executes line by line but the second (`viewProfile()`) function doesn't wait for `generateId();`

```
const generateId = async (data) => {
    const options = optionsBuilder("post","profile", data);
    try {
        const response = await axios(options);
        id = response.data.id;
        console.log(id);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}
const viewProfile = async (profileId) => {
    console.log('Test 2', profileId);
    const path = `blog/${profileId}`;
    const options = optionsBuilder("get", path);
    try {
        const response = await axios(options);
        console.log(response.data);  
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        }
    }
}
...
generateId(data);
viewProfile(profileId);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must execute them into an async scope:

```
(async function(){
    await generateId(data);
    await viewProfile(profileId);
})()
```

Otherwise they aren't parsed to be awaited and `viewProfile` will be executed right after `generateId`. :)

> As, if you are using the new ES2022 you can just `await` into the top level.

For newer Node.js versions:

```
await generateId(data);
await viewProfile(profileId);
```